# Enable case-sensitivity on Windows 7

Tags: windows, case-sensitive

I've got serious troubles with Windows 7 not having a case-sensitive file system.

I'm the only developer who's working on Windows in my team (and we wanna keep it that way for cross-OS checks), and I'm the one producing occasional errors due to Windows not crashing on files with different cases.

Is there any way to make Windows go crazy when I try to include 'aSdF.php' where I meant 'asdf.php'?

Comment: Try: http://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem

Comment: Always use lower case file names and you are safe.

Comment: @Styxxy: yeah, sounds like that'd work with autoloaders and tens of thousands of files all with case sensitive ClAsS nAmEs and corresponding file names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a programming viewpoint, you get case sensitivity on Windows by specifying the `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` flag when you call [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx).

You do just about have to call `CreateFile` directly to do that though -- a typical standard library (e.g., if you use `fopen` in C or `std::ifstream::open` in C++) will not pass that flag, so file names will be treated as case insensitive.